# data list are not keeping the old elements when new ones are added

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I've an upload list, the old data already in the list are removing from the list if I upload new data into the list. But I want to list all the data together. How can I fix this issue?

```
const [fileList, setFileList] = useState<AddedFile[]>([]);

const beginUpload = (file: File[]) => {
    const addedFiles = file
      ?.filter((item) => item !== null)
      .map((item): AddedFile => {
        if (item === null) {
          throw new Error('Item is null');
        }
        return {
          title: item?.name || '',
          fileName: item?.name || '',
        };
      });

    setFileList([...addedFiles, ...fileList]);

    file.forEach((item: File) => {
      onUpload(item, {
        title: item?.name || '',
        fileName: item?.name || '',
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update `setFileList([...addedFiles, ...fileList]);` to:

```
setFileList(currentList => {
  return [...addedFiles, ...currentList]
});
```

Reference:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate